# Galois group of a characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory, galois-theory

Quick question.

I have a 3x3 matrix with integer entries, say $J$. $J$ has rank 2 and determinant equal to zero. According to GAP the matrix has characteristic polynomial $f = X^3-9X^2+8X$. Moreover GAP tells me $J$ has splitting field the "rationals", $\mathbb Q$. How I do compute the Galois group of $f$? Is it non trivial?

Comment: As $0$ is a known root, it should be easy to find other roots by solving a quadratic and see that the splitting field is the rationals. And the Galois group of any field $F$ over itself is trivial.

Comment: Do you know what a splitting field is? The answer given by gap tells you the answer to your question!

Comment: I know now, and thanks for answering the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have that $f=X^3-9X^2+8X=X(X-1)(X-8)$. So the splitting field of $f$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ itself. So the Galois group of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is trivial.